# the color background is not applied to the block (html & css)

Tags: html, css

There are several answers on StackOverflow, but the code structure of each is too different to directly understand.

My question is to know why the blue background does not take all the block? I still have white spaces.

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLnkb.png)

dashboard.html

```
<nav>
   <div class="sidebar-button">
      <div class="menu-container">
         <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
         <span class="dashboard">Dashboard</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-summary-container">
         <span class="user">Utilisateur : Toto </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

style.css

```
.home-section nav .sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0a2558;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-container i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu-summary-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The code is available also on this following [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4hs3nh?file=src/styles.css).

I do not see what is missing?

Comment: It is because you put it in two different elements. Instead what you can use is the sidebar button that you have put in that example. That will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is the `align-items: center;` and `padding: 0 20px;` styles defined in the `.home-section nav` section. The issue is resolved when the specified styles are removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question, you've applied the background-color to the **`.homesection nav .sidebar-button`** rather than **`.home-section nav`**.

I've adjusted your styles.css as below:

```css
.home-section nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
    left: 330px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #0a2558;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
```

Great first question by the way! Very well structured and the stackblitz is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying the color to a element that is inside the nav, not the whole nav. The element inside the nav is not taking up all the space. You can either change the color of the nav itself:

```css
nav{
background: blue;
}
```

Or make the child fill up all the space in the nav:

```
.child{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```